# Upgrade API Level in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I've encountered some issues when I try to update my app to Marshmallow 6.0.1. I was previously working on 5.1.1 and I made some room for updating Android so I made sure to make it compatible with APIs 21-24. Right now, 6.0.1 runs on API 23 but for some reason the app crashes when it starts. 
I am running the latest Android Studio, 3.0.1 and I only want it to work on Android M.
I have two modules, one of them is an external library for the camera. I share my gradle settings:

For the 'app' module is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 332
        versionName "1.7.3d"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions{
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
 }
  repositories {
     jcenter()
     maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven" }
  }

 dependencies {
    compile project(':cam-library')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.54'
    compile 'com.jcraft:jzlib:1.1.3'}
```

The other one, the Follestad material camera module:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

 ext {
    PUBLISH_GROUP_ID = 'com.afollestad'
    PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID = 'material-camera'
    PUBLISH_VERSION = '0.3.2'
    PUBLISH_VERSION_CODE = 21
    SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = '25.3.0'
    VIDEO_PLAYER_VERSION = '0.2.12'
    MD_VERSION = '0.9.0.1'
    TARGET_SDK = 24
    BUILD_TOOLS = "24.0.1"
 }

android {
    compileSdkVersion TARGET_SDK
    buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK
        versionCode PUBLISH_VERSION_CODE
        versionName PUBLISH_VERSION
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
 }

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven" }
 }

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION"
    compile "com.afollestad:easyvideoplayer:$VIDEO_PLAYER_VERSION"
    compile "com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:$MD_VERSION"
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
 } 

//apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/afollestad/aidanfollestad.com/master/android-lib-release.gradle'
```

And lastly the gradle version settings:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What's wrong with this and why did it work on 5.1.1 and not on 6.0.1?

EDIT: This is the log

```
    03/05 11:49:51: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.test | XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Waiting for application to come online: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.test | XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Waiting for application to come online: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.test | XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Waiting for application to come online: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.test | XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Waiting for application to come online: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.test | XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Connecting to XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8820', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1486)
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=verify-at-runtime --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a9 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=verify-at-runtime --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a9 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=verify-at-runtime --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a9 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=verify-at-runtime --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a9 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=verify-at-runtime --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a9 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=verify-at-runtime --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a9 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=verify-at-runtime --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a9 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=verify-at-runtime --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a9 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=verify-at-runtime --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a9 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=verify-at-runtime --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a9 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=verify-at-runtime --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a9 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Verification of void XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity.injectIdleStatusFragment() took 2.665s
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/nanodlp.log: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:58)
W/System.err:     at XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.utils.Util.writeToLogFile(Util.java:113)
W/System.err:     at XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:222)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
W/System.err:   ... 16 more
V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity: Permission is revoked
W/Activity: Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX, PID: 5426
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                      at com.afollestad.materialcamera.internal.BaseCaptureActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(BaseCaptureActivity.java:336)
                      at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:3823)
                      at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.requestPermissions(ActivityCompatApi23.java:49)
                      at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:372)
                      at XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity.isStoragePermissionGranted(MainActivity.java:930)
                      at XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:223)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: plz post your log data

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to find the log data. Did I have to do it explicitely or every app stores some logs by itself? I guess I have to change it to debug mode and see what's happening but Android Studio doesn't give me any info.

EDIT: it only says " Error running app: Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8820): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect" "

Comment: just add Internet permission, and try again

Comment: Hi @Jorge. From android v6.0, some permissions have to be handled at runtime. Please look at the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) on runtime permission handling. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> call the askForMarshmallowPermissions method inside splash screen on create method.
> to grant danger premissions at run time
> you have to added External store read and camera premission.
>
>
>  Add premissions in Manifest.xml
> ```

```
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

askForMarshmallowPermissions(); call method in onCreate()

 private void askForMarshmallowPermissions() {
        List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

        final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();


        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            permissionsNeeded.add("Write to storage");

        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
            permissionsNeeded.add("Camera");

        if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
            if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
                // Need Rationale
                String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
                for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                    message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
                showMessageOKCancel(message,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreen.this,
                                        permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                        CommonUtils.REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                            }
                        });
                return;
            }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreen.this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    CommonUtils.REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }
        callAfterPermission();


    }

       private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            // Check for Rationale Option
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashScreen.this, permission))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


        private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreen.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        CommonUtils.showAlertDialogWithFinishActivity(SplashScreen.this,
                                "Please grant all required permissions to " +
                                        "continue running the app.",
                                CommonUtils.ALERT_TITLE, true, CommonUtils.NO_RESULT, null);
                    }
                })
                .create()
                .show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CommonUtils.REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED); 
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

                // Fill with results
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                if (perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // All Permissions Granted
                    //insertDummyContact();
                    callAfterPermission();
                } else {


                    // todo display alert when user  Denied Permission

                }
            }
            break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```